# Regex split string by last occurrence of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to split a string `<book name> by <author name>` into book and author names.

```
re.split(r'\bby\b', text, 0, re.I)
```

But problem arises when the book name contains the word "by" (e.g. `Death by Blackhole by Tyson` => `['Death', 'by Black...']`)

How do I split the string by the last occurrence of the search pattern?

I have a hunch -/+ve look-ahead/behind could be useful here, but currently splitting hairs trying to construct the proper syntax.

Comment: Try `re.split(r'\bby\b(?!.*\bby\b)', text, 0, re.I)`

Comment: Can't you just match the result? This [`^(.+)\bby\b(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/jqDLrM/1) matches both the author and the title (`+` is greedy, so the last occurrence is taken).

Answer (score 6):

You could use `findall` with a greedy `.*` before the `by`:

```
re.findall(r'(.*)\s+by\s+(.*)', text, re.I)
```

See it on [`repl.it`](https://repl.it/GQx8)

Answer (score 4):

You can reconstruct from the split:

```
parts = re.split(r'\bby\b', text, 0, re.I)
book, author = 'by'.join(parts[:-1]), parts[-1]
```

Or do a complete match:

```
match = re.match(r'(.*)\bby\b(.*)', text, re.I)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, it will match the last by, tested on your example

```
by(?!.*by.*)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this single regex:

`re.search('((.*( by )?.*) by (.*))',text).group(2,4)`

[image]